# How to create time field input mask

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

In my application, user could fill some time field.
In my case, I'd like help user to do that.
I want make a mask input for time(01:55) what only accept that user type four numbers.
So, when user type number 01 put after it this : and next, user could type 55.

Can you help me to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good maskTextInput here
http://bolao.zzl.org/MaskedTextInput/srcview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Bind to [change event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html#event%3achange), check what the user put in, add the colon (':') when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give Yahoo's [Flex Astra TimeInput component](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flex/timeinput/) a try. It seems to function as you describe.

Tangent